# jQuery closest A *or* B

Tags: jquery

I want to use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest `tr` *or* `div`. What's the proper syntax to "or" them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like `"tr,div"`.

Comment: Yeah... I tried that. Turns out the bug was somewhere else in my code and only *thought* I was using the wrong syntax. Thanks.